Pi zero 2w to use arm v7
I noticed that installing Raspberry Pi OS Lite on my pi zero 2w i'm using armv6 but from what I understand i should be able to use armv7.
How can i reach the goal to run on armv7?
I0ve tried both 64bit and 32 bit but I don't know how to proceed
Thanks in advance

Since you're asking about OS installation, rather than about an actual programming issue, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Try on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

ok nate. I need to wait 40 min before reposting it.
